# ASM Function Call & Ret - What does ret 0xC do?

Tags: assembly, x86, stdcall

What does ret do? Why is ret 0xC needed here? What if it was just ret and not ret 0xC or how about 0x4?

```
mov eax,[esp+10] // param3
mov ecx,[esp+0C] // param2
mov edx,[esp+08] // param1
push eax
push ecx
push edx 
mov ecx,esi
call File.exe+333330 
pop esi
ret 000C
```

Comment: You need to read. Read about epilogue and prolog, calling conventions and function return types. http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/672254/Win-x-Calling-Conventions

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no research effort put to get the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, `ret 00C` cleans up the stack after `call File.exe+333330`. Before the call, you pushed three 4-byte values onto the stack (the contents of `eax`, `ecx`, and `edx`). 4 * 3 = 12 = 0xC (in hex). If you had `ret` without a value, it would have returned from your subroutine, but wouldn't have cleaned up the stack at all. If you had `ret 4`, it would have only cleaned up one of the values. `ret 12` or `ret 0xC` takes care of all three.

See [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.asm.x86/Gh-hGhERSJ8) for a similar question.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks :) . Also, the link was a really good read as well. Double thanks :))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))).

Comment: Did anyone notice that there is a `pop esi` before the `ret 0c`? Secondly, if you don't properly clean up the stack it most likely won't return from the function and crash since the return location would have likely been garbage.

Comment: No, this is the bottom of a larger function; it cleans up *its caller's* stack so that caller doesn't need `add esp, 12`.  Presumably `File.exe+333330` is also stdcall or thiscall and cleans up the args for you by using `ret 12` itself.